# Error 404 Not found using DELETE method with fetch json

Tags: javascript, html, json, apache

I am creating a webpage using JSON API REST, along XAMPP with apache server.
The thing is that, I have bee using DELETE method so far, and so far so good. But now, I am really stuck, because I am doing a simple DELETE method, and it keeps returning me "404 Not found", when obviously I have checked several times that the resource that I want to delete exist on the JSON file.
Where is going on here? Its driving me crazy... Thank you so much in advance.

This is my JavaScript code

```
fetch(`http://localhost:3000/votes?photoId=${id}&userId=${userId}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer' + getToken(),

        }
    });
```

And this, my JSON file where the resource that I want to delete is:

```
"votes": [
{
  "photoId": "4",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 2
},
{
  "photoId": "2",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 4
},
{
  "photoId": "5",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 5
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 6
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 7
},
{
  "photoId": "1",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 8
},
{
  "photoId": "2",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 12
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 14
},
{
  "photoId": "1",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 15
},
{
  "photoId": "5",
  "userId": "7",
  "id": 16
},
{
  "photoId": "3",
  "userId": "11",
  "id": 17
},
{
  "photoId": "1",
  "userId": "11",
  "id": 18
},
{
  "photoId": "4",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 19
},
{
  "photoId": "2",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 20
},
{
  "photoId": "1",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 21
},
{
  "photoId": "6",
  "userId": "9",
  "id": 22
},
{
  "photoId": "6",
  "userId": "6",
  "id": 23
}
```

],

By the way, the fetch occur inside an async function, but anyways, I dont think that matters, I know that works because I have tested the code a lot. Its this fetch DELETE call what is freaking me out..
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you file json. give me root completed or try access file directly with you navigator.

Maby you file not correctly root or file already deleted

Comment: Root to my .json file:  C:\xampp\json-server . My resources are at  http://localhost:3000/votes  . I try to access the resource that I want to delete directly from the browser with the URL and works, so